# KL divergence of Variational Autoencoder not decreasing

Tags: probability, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, autoencoders

I have been trying to train a VAE to generate cat pictures. The images are of size 64 by 64. But upon training my reconstruction loss decreases whereas my KL loss remains constant/slightly increases. My code is based on the Keras tutorial shown here [here](https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/)

But my code for the training step has been modified as so

```
  def train_step(self,data):

    if isinstance(data, tuple):
      data = data[0]

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      mean, logvar = encoder(data)
      z = self.sampling(mean,logvar)
      x_logit = self.decoder(z)
      
      reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(keras.losses.MSE(data, x_logit))
      reconstruction_loss*= 64*64

      #KL_div_loss = -0.5*tf.reduce_mean(1 + logvar - tf.square(mean) - tf.exp(logvar))
      KL_div_loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(-0.5*tf.math.reduce_sum(1 + logvar - tf.square(mean) - tf.exp(logvar),axis=1))

      loss = reconstruction_loss + KL_div_loss

    grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_weights)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
    return {
          "total loss": loss,
          "reconstruction loss": reconstruction_loss,
          "kl divergence loss": KL_div_loss,
    }
```

I have seen a few articles on weighting the KL loss, but have no idea how to start.
Also is my code above the correct implementation?